# Orient db import data

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to do export/import in orient db 1.7.4 community edition between to different orient db servers running same version.

I did export database dbone which created dbone.json.gz file.
connected to other server created a new database and ran import database dbone.json.gz
it terminated with below error.

```
Error  on importing database 'dbthree' from file: dbthree.json.gz
Error while removing cluster '10'
E:\Installs\orientdb-community-1.7.4\orientdb-community-1.7.4\databases\dbthree\e.0.ocl: The process cannot access the  file because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception:

```
The process cannot access the  file because it is being used by another process.
```

Means you've a console or server open that locks the database.

Comment: It's not the case .. checked it thoroughly. its a stand alone machine.restarted the server and got the same error